# How do I pass DateTime parameters from View to Controller in ASP.net MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, parameters

I am trying to pass 3 parameters, one int, and 2 datetime to a controller with no luck. I have created custom Routes, but no matter what I do it never connects. 
In My View I have

```
@Html.ActionLink("Check Availability", "Check", new { id = item.RoomID, AD = ArrivalDate.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"), DD = DepartureDate.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") }, null)
```

In my Controller I have

```
   [RoutePrefix("RoomInfoes")]
   [Route("Check/{ID},{AD},{DD}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Check(int? id, string AD, string DD) {
```

I have tried numerous arrangements of routes and views, but never can connect.

The code above returns a 404 with

```
Requested URL: /RoomInfoes/Check/1,06-11-2014,06-11-2014
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it work if you remove the dates and pass only the int? By remove, I mean on the controller as well.

Comment: Yep, the int is passed. But no other parameters.

Comment: What does your link look like when hovered. BTW i couldnt get this to work at all with [HttpPost], only as a get request even when using ajax.actionlink and setting it to be post.

It works fine for me as a get request, which suggests that the params you have are right, I don't have the routeprefix in either. Does it work for you without that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you use attribute routing make sure you have it enabled:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); // add this line in your route config

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

then decorate your action like this:

```
[Route("RoomInfoes/Check/{ID},{AD},{DD}")]
public ActionResult Test(int? id, string AD, string DD)
```

The RoutePrefix has been removed because it can be used only on class declaration (the code will even doesn't compile). I removed the HttpPost attribute because I assumed that you want make a GET instead of POST.

then to generate a link pointing to this action you can simply write:

```
@Html.ActionLink("test", "Test", "Home", new { id = 5, AD="58", DD = "58" }, null)
```

the result will be:

```
<a href="/RoomInfoes/Check/5%2c58%2c58">test</a> (the commas in your url will be url encoded)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your comprehensive reply! I really appreciate the time you took to make it

Answer (score 1):

Do also have the Check Action method for serving HttpGet requests? If not, you will get 404 error.

Have you also done the `routes.MapRoute` in the `RouteConfig.cs`? This is required to render the correct URL with `@Html.ActionLink` helper method.

Try adding below code in `RouteConfig.cs`, if not already exists.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "RoomInfoes",
            url: "Check/{ID},{AD},{DD}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "RoomInfoes",
                action = "Check",
                ID = UrlParameter.Optional,
                AD = UrlParameter.Optional,
                DD = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
            );
```

You don't Need `Route` and the `RoutePrefix` attribute on the Action method.